# Getting two TypeErrors when trying to create a login form using ReactiveFormsModule

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently using Angular 11 and trying to make a login form with ReactiveFormsModule.
Immediately after the login page loads, a TypeError is thrown in the browser console.
After I type something in the input field, there is another TypeError that appears.
[image: TypeError]

I've searched the whole web for a solution and tried everything suggested by others with the same issue, but nothing solves mine. I just started learning Angular a month ago and I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I really can't find what it is.

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: [''],
      password: ['']
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  submitHandler(): void {
    const data = this.form.value;

    this.authService
      .login(data)
      .subscribe({
        next: () => {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      })
  }
}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<section class="login-wrapper">
    <form formGroup="form" class="login-form" (ngSubmit)="submitHandler()">
        <article class="login-body">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" formControlName="email">
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="/signup">Sign up</a></p>
        </article>
    </form>
</section>
```

**user.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UserRoutingModule } from './user-routing.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SignUpComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UserRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { CoreModule } from '../app/core/core.module';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../app/core/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from '../app/core/footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { UserRoutingModule } from '../app/user/user-routing.module';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    UserRoutingModule,
    UserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the bracket around `formGroup` at your form html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="login-form" (ngSubmit)="submitHandler()">
```

Comment: That solved my problem! Thank you so much! :)